# How to find the volume of the solid with integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

I need to find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the y-axis:
$$(y-1)^2 = x, x = 1$$

[image]

What definite integral should I use? With what boundaries? I tried this $\int_0^1(y-1)^4dy$,but I think it is wrong. I know that there is formula:
$$2\pi\int_{y1}^{y2} y(x)*x dx$$ But how can I "pull out" $y(x)$ Help please.

Comment: You're right, it's not $\int_0^1(y-1)^4\,dy$.

Comment: Hint: Every section with a constant $y$ is a ring of area $\pi1^2-\pi x^2$.

Comment: In the formula you know, what does $y(x)$ stand for?

Comment: Perhaprs expressing y through x?

Comment: No, it's more contextual than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try with this one (**cylinder method**):

$$2\pi\int_0^1 x(2\sqrt x)  dx$$

The correct formula is:

$$2\pi\int_{x_1}^{x_2} |f_1(x)-f_2(x)|\cdot x dx$$

In this case:

$$(y-1)^2 = x \implies y-1=\pm \sqrt x \implies y=\pm\sqrt x+1$$

$$f_1(x)=\sqrt x +1$$

$$f_2(x)=-\sqrt x +1$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @PashaMinigun You're welcome, take also a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution, Bye!

Comment: I think that it`s true form of formula which I mentioned earlier.